# React Router Error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It says undefined `pathname` but I don't know what's going wrong with my code. It says when I am  fetching data from backend to frontend then suddenly these error(s) occurred and before it can't perform react state update unmounted component no-ops. I have managed that error but these errors as typerror which says undefined 'pathname'.

section.js *when I uncomment from app.js then error appears*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './Section.css'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
// import api from './api/post';

function Section() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const FetchPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/posts');
    setPosts(await response.json([]));
  }
  console.log(posts)
  useEffect(() => {
    FetchPosts();
  }, []);

  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="mainmainsection">
        {
          posts.map((post) => {
            return (
              <div key={post._id} className="samplemain">
                <div className="samplecontainer">

                  <div key={post._id} className="r1">
                    <>
                      <img className='sectionimg' src={`http://localhost:5000/${post.image}`} alt="myimg" />
                      <Link to={post.title}></Link>
                      <h1 className="heading">{post.title}</h1>
                    </>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })

        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Section
```

App.js (main file to render)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef } from 'react';

import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Missing from './components/MissingPage';
import api from './components/api/post';
import Section from './components/Section';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Sectioninner from './components/Sectioninner'
import Socialicons from './components/Socialicons';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const componentMounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(async() => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await api.get ('http://localhost:5000/posts');
        if (componentMounted.current) {
          setPosts(response.data);
          setLoading(false);
          return () => {
            componentMounted.current = false;
          }
        }
       
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response) {
          // Not in the 200 response range 
          console.log(err.response.data);
          console.log(err.response.status);
          console.log(err.response.headers);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
      return () => {
        componentMounted.current = false;
      }
  }, [])

  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

  return (
       <Router>
          <Navbar />
          <Header search={search} setSearchResults={setSearch} />
        <Socialicons />
        <Footer />
        <Section />
        <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" posts={posts} element={<Sectioninner />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[in console with error   (it say's error is in link compontnent)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bpWk.png)

Comment: In your `App.js` you have a space after `await api.get (` in `useEffect`. Remove than and see if issue still exists.

Comment: not resolve that error... after removing space

Comment: @ShubhamWaje excess spaces do not matter in JS. They only matter when needed to separate identifiers and numbers from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because one of your post's title might be `undefined`.

```jsx
<Link to={post.title}></Link>
```

`Link`'s `to` attribute should not be undefined. Try checking and modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that there is at least one `Link` component with an undefined `to` prop.

```
<Link to={post.title}></Link>
```

Double check your data to ensure `post.title` is the correct property you are wanting to map into a link's target, or if it's correct you'll want to conditionally render the `Link` or filter the mapped `posts` array.

- Conditionally rendering the `Link`

  ```
  {post.title && (
    <Link to={post.title}>
      <h1 className="heading">{post.title}</h1>
    </Link>
  )}
  ```
- Filtering the `posts` array

  ```
  {posts
    .filter(post => !!post.title)
    .map((post) => (
      <div key={post._id} className="samplemain">
        <div className="samplecontainer">
          <div key={post._id} className="r1">
            <img
              className='sectionimg'
              src={`http://localhost:5000/${post.image}`}
              alt="myimg"
            />
            <Link to={post.title}>
              <h1 className="heading">{post.title}</h1>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  }
  ```